# How do I add Bower provided javascript to Google's Web Starter Kit

Tags: gulp, bower, google-web-starter-kit

I've installed some Bower packages, and would like to include them in the Gulp build process. I've tried adding them to `gulpfile.babel.js` in the `script` section:

```
gulp.task('scripts', () =>
    gulp.src([
      // Note: Since we are not using useref in the scripts build pipeline,
      //       you need to explicitly list your scripts here in the right order
      //       to be correctly concatenated
      './bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      './bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js',
      './app/scripts/main.js'
      // Other scripts
    ])
      .pipe($.newer('.tmp/scripts'))
      .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe($.babel())
      .pipe($.sourcemaps.write())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/scripts'))
      .pipe($.concat('main.min.js'))
      .pipe($.uglify({preserveComments: 'some'}))
      // Output files
      .pipe($.size({title: 'scripts'}))
      .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('.'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'))
);
```

But that builds a seperate minified `main.min.js` in the /dist/scripts directory.

How can I import a script into the build pipeline to have it included in app/scripts/main.js?

Surely it can't be this difficult to do something as straightforward as adding Bower provided JS to a project. I can't find anything in documentation as to what's best practice.